# How to use reg ex to count occurrences of a sub-string within a string (.NET Framework)

Tags: .net, regex, string

If a string contains something like:  https://website1.comhttps://website2.com

How do I create a regex that will return a value of 2. Meaning, since "https://" occurs twice in that string, it should return 2.

I'm currently using this regex to parse between the two "https://" but have no idea how to adapt it to return the number of "https//" in the string (2 in this case).

```
(?s)(?<=https://).+?(?=https://)
```

Using the .NET Framework. Thanks a ton for your help

Comment: use this regex `https:\/\/` and then count the matched results.

Comment: i think you don't need a regex at all, just count for the substring `https://` ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tricky non-regex way:

```
var inp = "https://website1.comhttps://website2.com";
var cnt_nonrgx = inp.Length - inp.Replace("https://", "https:/").Length;
```

Here is the regex way:

```
var cnt_rgx = Regex.Matches(inp, "https://").Count;
```

And a classic way:

```
var cnt_liof = 0;
var idx = inp.IndexOf("https://");
while (idx > -1)
{
    cnt_liof += 1;
    idx = inp.IndexOf("https://", idx + 1);
}
```

All results are `2`.